# Split string into even numbers forming a square

Tags: javascript

My objective is to split string (less than 80 characters) evenly to create a square or rectangle of strings.

```
var squareStr = function(str) {

}

console.log(squareStr('whatwonderfulday'));
console.log(squareStr('if life was easy god then god would not have given us brain to think'));
```

should output:

```
what
wond
erfu
lday

iflifewa
seasythe
ngodwoul
dnothave
givenusb
raintoth
ink
```

is this possible? I've been told I can use Math.sqrt but I'm not too sure how.

Thanks.

Comment: If the length of the string isn't a number evenly divisible by four then this couldn't work.

Comment: Sure it's possible, what have you tried?

Comment: take a look at [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: I have an answer ready to post here, but i'm waiting to see what you have tried or researched so far.

Comment: I've tried str.match(/.{1,3}/g) - but that only does it by fixed amount. I want it to do it calculate it on its own (if that's possible).

Comment: Use `floor(Math.sqrt(string.length))` as the length of each line.

Comment: Your second example is not a square. It has 8 columns but only 7 rows.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan What does division by 4 have to do with it? And his second example shows that the last line can be incomplete.

Comment: The title says you want a square, but the question says "square or rectangle". Which is it? And if it's a rectangle, are there constraints on the height or width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for loop to slice the string into the pieces and add a new line (`\n`) at the end of each chunk.

If you want to automatically use the square root of the string length you can do it like this:

```js
function squareCode(string){
  let squareString = "";
  string = string.replace(/\s/g, '');
  const splitNum = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(string.length));
  for(i=0; i<= string.length; i+=splitNum){
    squareString = `${squareString}${string.slice(i, i+splitNum)}\n`;
  }
  return squareString;
}

console.log(squareCode('whatwonderfulday'));
console.log(squareCode('if life was easy god then god would not have given us brain to think'));
console.log(squareCode('asdfasdf asdfasdfasd fasdfwe wer df gf dgdfgertqewdfsf fgdgewfwdsgewerfsd fdgdfgqefasdf'));
```

In the following function you'll pass in the string you want to slice as well as the number you want to slice at:

```js
function squareCode(string, splitNum){
  let squareString = "";
  string = string.replace(/\s/g, '');
  for(i=0; i<= string.length; i+=splitNum){
    squareString = `${squareString}${string.slice(i, i+splitNum)}\n`;
  }
  return squareString;
}

console.log(squareCode('whatwonderfulday', 4));
console.log(squareCode('if life was easy god then god would not have given us brain to think', 8));
```

Comment: I think the function is supposed to figure out the sizes `4` and `8` automatically, not take it as a parameter.

Comment: @Barmar.... Better?

Comment: You should remove the spaces before getting string.length.

Comment: @Barmar haha yeah you're right. Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for and makes the most sense.

Comment: @Binny.H Glad I could help.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Better not to implicitly create global variables.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this function. It replace all the empty spaces, then convert the string into an array and chunk it. Finally if merge every chunk and apply `\n` to each one.

```js
var squareStr = function(str, chunk) {
  str = str.replace(/ /g, '')
  str = str.split('');
  temp = []
  for (i=0; i<str.length; i+=chunk)
    temp.push(str.slice(i,i+chunk));
  return temp.map(function(a){return a.join('')+"\n"}).join('')
}

console.log(squareStr('whatwonderfulday', 4));
console.log(squareStr('if life was easy god then god would not have given us brain to think', 8));
```

Comment: I think the function is supposed to figure out the chunk size automatically, not take it as a parameter.

Comment: OP did not specified that. But it would be just get the `abs` of the `sqrt` of the total string length and divide it by 2. That would get the numbers of chunk to use.

Comment: Why divide by 2?

Comment: To get a rectangle. If you only get the sqrt you will get a square. For example, 16 sqrt will be 4 making it 4 lines of 4 chars. while dividing it whill be 2 that means 8 lines of 2 chars. Sorry, didnt notice that an square is ok as well.

Comment: Better not to implicitly create global variables.

Answer (score 1):

So many ways of doing that...

All other answers here are correct too, here's my approach, a more "readable" answer, using very basic recurses...

You have should at least tried...

I also have included a check to see if the string lenght is under 80.

```js
var squareStr = function(str, charsPerLine) {
  if (str.length > 80){
    return;
  }
  str = str.replace(/ /g,'')
  var stringSplited = str.split('');  
  var newString = '';
  
  stringSplited.forEach(function(letter,index){
    if (index % charsPerLine == 0 && newString.length > 0){
      newString += '\n'; //IF YOU WANT TO USE IT IN THE HTML, USE '<br>' HERE
    }
    newString += letter;
  }); 
  console.log(newString);
  return newString;
}


squareStr('whatwonderfulday', 4);
squareStr('if life was easy god then god would not have given us brain to think', 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're dealing with *really long* strings, I don't see a reason not to use `replace` to insert a newline every *n* characters:

```js
function squareText(input) {
  const inputNoSpaces = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
  const partLen = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(inputNoSpaces.length));
  const replaceExpr = new RegExp(`.{1,${partLen}}`, 'g');
  return inputNoSpaces.replace(replaceExpr, '$&\n');
}

const input = 'if life was easy then god would not have given us brain to think';
console.log(squareText(input));
```

This just calculates the line length and then creates a new RegExp that matches that many characters and uses it to replace each match with itself plus a newline.